# Upvote an answer with accepted

Tags: discussion, reputation

I received 4 upvote on an answer with accepted but I received 35 Reputation only.

It should be 55. Why I received only 35?

Any reason?

[image]

Comment: Congrats. You hit the *rep cap*. You can earn only 200 rep from upvotes a day.

Comment: But don't be surprised if that reputation will be mostly gone by tomorrow. It seems you've become the victim of serial upvoting. That will most likely be reversed.